# Null when update Date field - MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update date field in my db. Query like this:

```
$q = "update news set data = STR_TO_DATE('2011-03-05','%Y-%m-%d'), title = '".$title."', content='".$content."',....";
```

works great, but:

```
$q = "update news set data = STR_TO_DATE('".$data."','%Y-%m-%d'), title = '".$title."', content='"...";
```

it is not working :(

I got date:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
```

and it has a value "2013-04-13". I trimmed date and show in popup window and value is correct; Plz help :)

**UPDATE**
It is strange to me, but if i'm using:

```
$q = "insert into news set data = CAST('".$data."' AS DATE), title = '".$title."', content='".$content."'...";
```

it works perfectly fine. Only in insert not in update

Script for table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `data` date NOT NULL, `title` text NOT NULL, `content` text NOT NULL, `img` text NOT NULL, `n_img` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `id` (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;
```

Comment: You'd better do PHP `var_dump()` on your `$_POST['data']` - instead of a popup window (I suppose it's javascript `alert()`?) it can show some "tricky" symbols in variables.

Comment: I'd say, do `var_dump($q);`both times and compare.

Comment: You should escape the post data first. Maybe have a read here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: after doing `var_dump($data);` it returns good data "2013-04-13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using `STR_TO_DATE`? looks like your date is already in the correct format. try removing it and just inserting as is?

might want to escape it first though.

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["data"]);
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't help. I'm using `STR_TO_DATE` because i have tried many options and with `STR_TO_DATE` it start working in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @MarcinSzubert no, `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't going to fix your problem, it's just giong to protect your website from sql injection. There may be an issue with your table structure, the PHP looks fine. Can you export the table and post it in your question?

Comment: Done. Thank you for your commitment

Comment: @MarcinSzubert I've never seen that syntax before on an insert query. first, stop trying to get all fancy with the date. it's not nessecary, if you're doing everything else correctly, you should be able to insert the date as it is, without any `cast` or `str_to_date`, etc.

Comment: @MarcinSzubert Once you get everything else working, if there is an issue with the date, you can go back and look at it.

Comment: @MarcinSzubert here are a few things to consider. When you're doing an update you really should have a WHERE caluse so that mysql know which row to update, otherwise it will update all of them. If your query works in PMA and You KNOW that PHP has got a successful connection with the db then the ONLY other possibility is that there is something going on in your variables. you need to escape them ALL.

Comment: @MarcinSzubert if there is a single or double quote in ANY of your form input then it will mess up your query. aside from that I'm not really seeing any fatal errors. It's gotta be in your input. do `echo $q; exit;` and make sure it looks right.

Comment: You were right. Something was bad with the date even if it was displayed in var_dump properly it has 4 more chars (string length should be 10, was 14). I remove all `cast`, `str_to_date`, and leave only `mysql_real_escape_string`. Thanks very much!